# Contact Form 7 always redirecting to the same page when submit

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have use this plugin in all the web sites I worked. I used it for my current site as well with latest wordpress. But I am getting following error.

Instead of jQuery submission it is redirecting the page and this hash “#wpcf7-f1693-o1” appending to the URL. If I fill correctly and submit, mail is sending fine except this hash appending and page redirecting issue.

Why it is redirecting and appending the hash (form ID/action) to the current URL.

Assume I am submitting my contact us form. Then the resulting URL is contact-us/#wpcf7-f1693-o1

Thanks

Comment: Post your html and jquery code here, if you could. Sounds maybe like your sending your form to phpself? But it's hard to debug without more information.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are using your contact form short-code inside html form tag
remove form-tag then it should be working

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was disabling Litespeed Cache JS deferring

Answer (score 0):

This is because your contact form is working in non-AJAX submission mode.

In short, a correctly configured contact form in Contact Form 7 works submitting the form without reloading the current page. The messages shows up just bellow the form, without any page reload.

If the form doesn’t work like this and instead reloads the page, it is probable because Contact Form 7’s JavaScript is not functioning on your site. Possible causes for this:

- **JavaScript file is not loaded.** This is due to your theme’s template, which is missing calling functions for queuing JavaScript.
- **Conflicts with other JavaScript** Many plugins and themes load their own JavaScript. Some of them may have been created incorrectly and therefore conflict with other plugins. In most cases, you may be able to find JavaScript errors with your browser’s script console when such conflicts occur.
- **HTML structure is not valid** If the original HTML structure is not valid, it will fail to work.

*Reference: https://contactform7.com/why-isnt-my-ajax-contact-form-working-correctly/*